# Do I need to prepare statement on every open or can prepare only once in PDO PHP SQLite3

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I found this example on net for inserting in SQLite usong PHP PDO

```
# no placeholders - ripe for SQL Injection!  
$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO folks (name, addr, city) values ($name, $addr, $city)");  

# unnamed placeholders  
$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO folks (name, addr, city) values (?, ?, ?); 

# named placeholders 
$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO folks (name, addr, city) value (:name, :addr, :city)");
```

I am closing connection after every command ( another app only reads and mine only inserts). Do I need to prepare statement on every open or can prepare only once ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$userprep = $userdbc->prepare("
    INSERT INTO Users (userID, userPass, userName, userEmail)
    VALUES (:userID, :userPass, :userName, :userEmail)
");
$userprep->execute($newUser);
```

heres an example of my code to insert a new user using placeholders..

`$newUser` is an associative array.

once you have prepared a statement you can execute that statement as many times as you wish, for example if i had a nested array of users to enter i could just run this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($newUser); $i++){
    $userprep->execute($newUser[$i]);
}
```

(the nested arrays would have to of course use associative keys)

Hope this is of some help..

Comment: I may not have answered the question perfectly, but it does give an example where a prepared statement can be used more than once - showing that Danka could indeed make good use of the prepared statement without having to close/re-open/repeat. It was an accepted answer - so it was at least of some help :)

Comment: It doesn't answer the "can i use the same prepared statement on different connections" though...